# SQL join query efficiency

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question about joining tables and how long they take to process.

It's not directly a problem, but rather that someone could shed some light on why one method takes far longer then another.

Why does this top method take 90 seconds to complete while the bottom method takes less than a second?

```
SELECT *
FROM Cables C
LEFT JOIN Fibres F on C.OID = F.OID1 or C.OID = F.OID2


SELECT *
FROM Cables C
LEFT JOIN Fibres F  on C.OID = F.OID1
LEFT JOIN Fibres F2 on C.OID = F2.OID2
```

Comment: I think it is the ON condition.
in the first one he will look for two parameters at once,
In the second one he makes the first, then another
I think searching will be easier for SQL

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the indexes that are present on each table please?

Comment: Please note that both queries are not equivalent at all - so the question why one takes X amount of time while the other takes Y amount of time is irrelevant. You are comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: Can you maybe provide us with sample data?

Comment: I have found that using "OR" in a join is generally going to cause slow queries. The second one is faster because there is no OR, so the join is exact and doesn't have to evaluation multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already by @ZoharPaled, the queries are not same to compare.

However, if you just want understand the query time between 2 of them: It depends on SQL engine that how many tasks and what type of tasks it's being performed to get your query result.

You can monitor this by enabling `Execution Plan`. Use the shortcut `ctrl + M` in SSMS and run the queries again to see their execution plans.

Answer (score 0):

The queries are *not* equivalent, because the first will return two rows and the second puts the information in additional columns.  The results are even more disparate if there are multiple matches in the `Fibres` table, but I'm guessing that is not expected.

What is the difference?  SQL engines optimize joins -- they try not to generate the Cartesian product and filter them.  Most `join` *algorithms* (what the database actually does) work best on equi-joins.  These are joins (inner or outer) with equality conditions between keys.

Happily, equi-joins are also the most common type of `join` and they solve most problems.  These algorithms include index lookups, merge joins, and hash joins.

When the conditions are not equality, then the default is typically to use the dreaded nested-loop join.  This does create the Cartesian product and then filter the results.

`OR` (and `IN`) are examples of non-equality conditions.  So, if there is no equality, then the optimizer chooses a less efficient mechanism.

The differences in your timings show how much the `join` algorithm can affect performance -- or, I might say, how important the optimizer is.

That said, there is nothing in the definition of SQL that requires this behavior.  There are algorithms that will optimize your query.  But, they are generally not worth including, because these cases are fairly rare (you can petition Microsoft to change this if you disagree).

In fact, if you stored the data in a normalized format -- that is, with a separate row for each id -- then you would not face this issue.